# Laravel Object to Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, laravel-5

I try for some time to use an array instead of a collection, as Laravel does.

I tried to do this method, without success:

```
Event::listen(StatementPrepared::class, function ($event) {
    $event->statement->setFetchMode(...);
});
```

As explained on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0, but it's not working...

I also tried to do this:

```
DB::table('users')->where([...])->take(1)->get()->toArray();
```

But it's doing:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [uid] => 1 [...]) )
```

I know there is more about it on the forum, but they are all outdated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toArray` is changing the collection of objects into an array of objects, like it should.  If you want the objects inside the collection to also be arrays, you need to first convert each object:

```
$collection = DB::table('users')->where([...])->take(1)->get();

$array = $collection->map(function($obj){
  return (array) $obj;
})->toArray();
```

To use this function in your whole app, you could add a collection macro in the `boot` method of one of your service providers:

```
Collection::macro('toArrays', function () {
  return $this->map(function ($value) {
    return (array) $value;
  })->toArray();
});
```

And this at the top of the file of the service providers:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

Then anywhere you get a set of DB results you can just call `toArrays` on it:

```
DB::table('users')->where([...])->get()->toArrays();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it just once for the whole site, because, I'd just like to use that.

Comment: see my edit for a simple way to use this function on any collection in your app @KarylLamoureux

Comment: Thank you, just a little thing, now it's `Array ( [0] => Array ( [uid] => 1 [...]) )`. Is it a way to remove the first array ? to just have `Array ( [uid] => 1 [...])` in the macro ? @Jeff

Comment: when you use `take(1)->get()` it still returns a collection.  You need to use `first()` if you want a single object as the response, see @Alexey's answer for that.

Comment: I have replace `take(1)->get()` with `first()` and it said: _Call to undefined method stdClass::toArrays()_

Comment: By using `Collection::macro` you created the `toArrays()` function on the Collection class.  `get()` returns one of those collections.  `first()` simply returns the object you are requesting (rather than a collection of objects) so it no longer contains the `toArrays()` method.  You would just type cast it with `(array) $object`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161993/discussion-between-karyl-lamoureux-and-jeff).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting just one object, use the `first()` method:

```
$object = DB::table('users')->where([...])->first();
$array = (array)$object;
```

Comment: Good answer, I didn't notice he was only taking 1.  You might need to typecast it rather than call `toArray()` because it is just a basic object

Comment: @Jeff yes, I've just tested it and updated the answer at the same time you've commented. OP needs to use `(array)` casting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Collection's [map method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map) to turn each object into an array.